# How to get my enter key working properly in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, enter

When i press the command line it shows the hint:

[image]

---

When i press enter it comes out like this:

[image]

---

I tried to fix it but was not expecting any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should really have more tags to this question, such as IDE, VSCode etc. You should really use the "Tab" key as opposed to the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the blue-bordered setting below.
[image: solution]

If it does not work, you can try to seek other suggestion-related settings.

For example this is checked for me too: [image]

If it worked, you're welcome :)